# Obtaining the DistributedTaskContext in a custom TFS Build/Release Script

Tags: powershell, tfs, release-management

I'm using TFS 2015 Update 2 along with the new Build/Release system. I have a powershell script I'm executing via the Powershell Task. This task executes a powershell script that needs access to the $distributedExecutionContext magic variable I see in many different VSTS Task code samples.

This script in question is not technically a task, but instead is being executed by the Powershell task that comes delivered with TFS.

No matter what I do, I can't see to obtain the $distributedExecutionContext variable. It's always null. Here is an example:

```
Import-Module "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.Internal"

if($distributedTaskContext)
{
    #... this never happens
}
```

Is this variable only available if the powershell being run is being run inside an actual task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default powershell task that you are using runs the script entirely as a different process and the `$distributedTaskContext` variable is not available to the script.

It is only available only to the task's powershell script.

If you are going to write a custom task, I would like you to use the new [vsts-task-lib SDK](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-task-lib/blob/master/powershell/Docs/README.md) which improves a lot over old SDK.

Comment: So there is no way to obtain the task context "deeper" than the task itself? I.e, inside the poweshell script that the Powershell task is executing?

I'll write a custom task if I have to, but for most stuff, plain powershell scripts have been enough to get the job done. In this case, I want to publish some test results back to TFS, and it's proving to be difficult without that context.

Comment: I ended up just writing a VSTS extension, and this provided the context. The TFS team should seriously consider allowing people to obtain that context ambiently in any script being run by the VS agent.